# How to Zoom Object in Forge Viewer using Object ID

Tags: autodesk-forge

We have uploaded multiple BIM models in our web application and we have used Forge Aggregate View to display the all the uploaded BIM models as a merged format.
Also we have used Object ID to zoom the object in Forge Viewer. But in Forge Aggregate View we have displayed multiple files. Each file contains the same object id which is point out the different equipments.
For Example:
File 1 contains object id "2204" (Object name: A)
file 2 contains same object id "2204" (Object name: B)
I would like to zoom Object A (File 1) in Forge Viewer. So we pass the Object ID 2204 to the Forge Viewer. But the Object B (File 2) has been zoomed in Forge Viewer instead of Object A (File 1).

Kindly provide your suggestion to zoom the correct object in correct file. Kindly let us know do we have any C# code (function) to pass the file name/URN along with Object ID to zoom the selected object.

Thank you for your quick support.

Answer (score 0):

In multi-model scenarios, you need to tell the viewer which one of the models you're referring to (because dbIDs are only unique within a single model). In case of the [fitToView](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#fittoview-objectids-model-immediate) method, you can pass the model as the 2nd parameter.

In order to obtain an actual instance of the `Model` class, you can use methods like [viewer.getVisibleModels()](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#getvisiblemodels).

EDIT:

As an example, if you know the URN (let's call it `myUrn`) of the specific model you want to use, try the following:

```js
const model = viewer.getVisibleModels().find(m => m.getData().urn === myUrn);
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. but here the question is how to pass the model name in Viewer.fitToView() and Viewer.select() methods. shall we give the model name directly as a parameter?

Comment: I don't think you can give models custom names. As I mentioned in my answer, you will need to somehow identify the model you're interested in in the list returned by `viewer.getVisibleModels()`, and pass the actual model object as the additional parameter to the `viewer.fitToView()` method.

Comment: The identification could happen through the model metadata, for example, or by its URN which is available via `model.getData().urn`.

Comment: Thank you Petr Broz. It is working now..Thanks a lot..

Comment: We have one more question : If we click or double click in any of the objects in the Forge Viewer that object will get zoomed in the forge viewer. But how to find out the object id and model URN of the selected equipment. Kindly share the sample code.

Comment: There are various ways. For example, you can use `viewer.getAggregateSelection` to get information about the selected objects, their IDs, and the models they belong to. Refer to this blog post for more information: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/multi-model-refresher.